# How can I use existing realm db file in swift?

Tags: swift, realm

I have a realm db file where the data is stored
I would like to use this file in a new project
Is there a way for realm to use an existing db file?

Comment: The question is unclear. Realm stores it's data in a file which can be used by different projects as long as the Realm Models are set up to match. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question
I have a default.realm file
I want to copy this file to a new project. Is it possible?

Comment: You don't 'copy a file to a project' unless you are [Bundling A Realm](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-legacy/docs/swift/latest/#realms) in the project itself which would be a read only realm. You can copy your default.realm file to where ever you want it. It's just a database document (like a word processing or spreadsheet document) and can be opened by any app you create - as long as the Realm Object models in the app match the Realm file. That's why your Realm document can also be opened with Realm Studio, for example.